# When does WebSecurity.ChangePassword fail when "new password is invalid"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, security, simplemembership

This is the code for changing a password in the default AccountController scaffolded in MVC 4:

```
// ChangePassword will throw an exception rather 
//than return false in certain failure scenarios.
bool changePasswordSucceeded;
try
{
    string userName = User.Identity.Name;    
    changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(userName, 
                                                         model.OldPassword,
                                                         model.NewPassword);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    changePasswordSucceeded = false;
}

if (changePasswordSucceeded)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("",
    "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
}
```

My issue is that the message is unclear. If the current password is incorrect then that's fine but if the new password is invalid I'd like to present a better message to the user telling them what's wrong and I'd like to understand the "failure scenarios" better so that I can tailor the message.

The documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.changepassword%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) is specific about the exceptions and I don't think these should be swallowed in the Action and reported as invalid passwords.

So why is the "new password is invalid" a possibility here? Can I remove it if I'm only using the SimpleMembershipProvider without OAuth in my application?

**Edit:** NB This Data Annotation also appears in the "RegisterModel" class so there is a password validity check here too

```
[StringLength(100, 
ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", 
MinimumLength = 6)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Summary

*This is now a long answer, so I have edited it into sections. I am not a security expert compared to a user like [rook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183528/rook), and even he says not to trust his security answers, or anybody else's. Test and understand it yourself, always. Any web developers reading this should read [the OWASP top ten web security flaws](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project), use online guidance such as [Trustworthy Computing](http://www.microsoft.com/about/twc/en/us/developer.aspx) and, of course, [Mr. Bruce Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/). Security is complicated and too big for any one of us, so use frameworks which do the work according to best practice when you can. Above all, keep it all [in perspective](http://xkcd.com/970/).*

See below for more detail on these summary answers:

1. The message to the user *is deliberately* ambiguous, it can be argued that this is for security reasons (see below)
2. Ref. the "failure scenarios", they are mainly due to invalid input which should already be caught by model validation, an incorrect current password, or edge case exceptions
3. The exceptions are swallowed and presented as one either because the original developer was lazy, or because they believed there should be a single return message for all cases (see 1 above)
4. "New password is invalid" is probably not a possibility for the code you've highlighted *as long as your attributes match, or are more restrictive than the length restrictions within ChangePassword*. But, see (1) above.
5. Can I remove it? See (1) above.
6. Good point, see below for discussion.

### Original Answer - the conceptual attack vector

Think about it from a security perspective:

- I wander up to your mobile/tablet/laptop sitting on the bar/coffee shop table (or desktop computer in the home/office)
- I think I might know your password
- I go to "change password" and type in what I think your password is NOT
- I deliberately a put a 1 character new password in

The machine tells me

> "current password incorrect"

Now I put in try again with what I think your current password is:

> "new password invalid"

I now know your password, but you don't know I do as I haven't changed anything.

*Footnote: I got the first set of logic wrong, deleted it, edited it and reposted, but hey - [I'm not Bruce](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2010/11/changing_passwo.html)*

#### A similar attack

There are many combinations of this attack, but it's just like email harvesting from a bad login system. Think what happens if I get two different messages when I try to "recover password" using an email address:

- *An email has been sent to your address* (for an email in your database)
- *Your email could not be found* (for an obviously fake email address)

then I can easily find out valid member emails from your site for a targeted phishing attack on that user, or just build a list of valid email addresses for spam.

#### A possible solution

A more user friendly, but equally secure error message for our password change in both cases would be:

> "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid. Remember that your password is case sensitive, and new passwords must have [[64 letters/5 numbers/4 characters](http://xkcd.com/936/)/3 names of greek gods]"

To stay sane, keep this in the context of your application use, but remember you have a responsibility in a bigger eco-system, and [users share passwords between websites](http://www.xkcd.com/1200/), whether you like it or not.

### When does ChangePassword return false?

Regarding the question part about when ChangePassword returns false:

Essentially `WebSecurity.ChangePassword`:

In summary, it returns `false` if:

1. any of the arguments fail null, empty or length checks; or
2. the database connection fails; or
3. the `UserId` no longer exists in the database; or
4. the current password is incorrect; or
5. (and it will, obviously, set `changePasswordSucceeded = false` if any other exception happens).
6. There is *no* `newPassword` validity check within the call to `ChangePassword`

So in theory, if you have your validation attributes in place correctly, and ignoring the edge cases, it can only `return false` if we have an edge case (the user has been deleted, between the Get and Post, or we can't hit the database, or the current password is invalid).

This all holds true even in the case that attackers bypass the UI in the browser (which they will) as the Action itself calls `IsValid` on the model.

#### The client side message

*There is a serious disclaimer here: I don't spend my life working on security. I follow secure-by-design principles (I keep up with [the OWASP top ten project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project), for instance) and believe I have a good awareness of the most important security principles. I may therefore have got some of this logic wrong.*

If the client side "password requirements" validation is not there - what happens? The user has to wait for the Post to return to find out what happened.

If the client side "password requirements" validation *is* there, does it weaken our interface? I don't believe so.:

- the server still performs both requirements and current password validation
- the server does not distinguish between the two failure scenarios (actually it does, see below)
- therefore the server is only going to tell you if the current password is valid when it is, and when the password therefore changes.
- Hopefully the site also:

  - Prevents changing back to an old password
  - Sends an email notification that your password has been changed (maybe wait for 15 minutes in order to prevent the attacker deleting it from the email you also left open when you left your phone lying around unlocked in a bar with our website opened in it, and our email open as well)

MVC doesn't, AFAIK, do either of these things, so that is where this starts to fall apart.

It also falls apart because we return a different error and message from the server due to the `Model.IsValid` test inside the action, which enforces the new password validation and the different error message for this failure. Therefore, in its current implementation, the single error message approach *is flawed*.

### Summary

So would I get change the way this is all done? In the hope that I would improve the other parts in time, I probably wouldn't, other than changing the return message to be a bit longer and more informative.

*This is a personal opinion, it could be argued the other way*

---

The detail:

- calls `Membership.GetUser(userName, true).ChangePassword(...)`. In the case of an ArgumentException [see docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepassword.aspx) it will return `false`.
- it then calls `ChangePassword` on the actual provider (e.g. [`SimpleMembershipProvider.ChangePassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.changepassword.aspx)), and will return `false` if that fails.

The actual provider implementation gets complex. For `SimpleMembershipProvider`, for example,

- it might pass the call to the "previous provider" if it hasn't been initialised yet.
- Otherwise it might throw an `ArgumentExceptions` (bubbling up to the `catch` and `return false` in `MembershipUser.ChangePassword`) if the password/username is empty, null, too long etc.
- If that doesn't happen then it will

  - try and get the `UserId` from the database (returns false if fails),
  - checks the current password is correct (returns false if fails),
  - and finally updates the password with an UPDATE query, setting `PasswordChangedDate` for you while it goes
- it then updates the internal data on the `MembershipUser`

Comment: OK. I can buy into that. But the scaffolded RegisterModel class puts the invalid password check in a Data Annotation, so the action would not get called and we have exactly the problem you describe. So, does the call to WebSecurity.ChangePassword ever return false or throw an exception for an invalid password? If it doesn't then I can safely make the data annotation and the incorrect password messages be identical and stop swallowing the exception at this point.

Comment: @Colin. You are completely right about the annotation, it's not consistent, and note that if you did have it implemented the other way I described the order of your checks would impact the way the attack could work.

Comment: @Colin. My edit addresses your attribute point. `ChangePassword` returns `false` (**provider dependent logic follows**) for both incorrect current password and edge cases like the database connection or a deleted user account, but not for an invalid new password. "_If ... then I can ... stop swallowing the exception_": I would definitely distinguish between exception cases and `false`, but I would not split out the message for the old and new password cases. This is possibly personal preference.

Comment: @Colin. Important update - the Model.IsValid test in the server-side Action undoes all our good work in using a single error message. It took me a while to spot that.